Best Way to Troubleshoot Breaker Tripping on 3-Way Switch with No Changes to Wiring
I have a set of lights on the side of my house that don't get used often. They are on a 3 way switch. I went to turn them on today from switch A and nothing happened so I went to to Switch B and flipped it and again nothing. I then went and checked the breaker and it had tripped. I reset the breaker and it tripped again right away. I went and reset both A & B switch such that the lights would be off which allows me to reset the breaker without it tripping. If I then change position on either of the switches the breaker trips.
No wiring changes have been made and no pictures (or anything else) hung that could have hit the wires. However, I cannot rule out a mouse or other critter like a squirl or chipmunk chewing on the wire.
So what is my best approach to determine if one of the switches is bad, if one of the two connected outside fixtures is bad or if something happened to the wiring. I am trying to do this in a logical manner without having to take out each switch and each fixture. The biggest issue is that I cannot rule out animal damage on certain parts of the wire run as I would not be able to inspect without tearing off siding.
Thoughts on my best approach to troubleshoot?
EDIT: I should say there is another/different switch and set of lights on the same circuit and they turn on and off fine without tripping the breaker. So the problem lies somewhere between Switch A, Switch B and the fixture.

A simple breaker, mouse(fried) is a good guess.  A GFCI breaker might just be moisture/water in the light fixture.  Turn off the breaker and check each switch/fixture, before ripping walls open.  A switch a bit loose might have moved over enough to touch the box.

Do you have a DMM?

Not a GFCI breaker, standard 15 amp. Based on the location of the fixture doubtful it is water, so mouse may be the issue. I have a basic multimeter any DIY'er would have.  The kind you can switch between DC and AC, red and black probes, handles different voltages, continuity, resistance, etc.  Typical $50 type thing.
